# Why can't I open system settings?

Tags: settings

When I click on the icon in the dock it only bounces.

When I open it via Cerebro it only opens a blank panel.

[image: Clicking 'All Settings' does nothing]

It's really hard to use an OS with no settings. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I helped an individual on Reddit with a problem kinda close to what you've got happening and it ended up being an issue with broken packages in the end. Try the following in Terminal:

First, lets's try to reinstall Switchboard with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall switchboard
```

Once this is done, let's do a update via the command line with:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once the above is done, give the machine a reboot and try opening System Settings.

If that didn't do it, we can try fixing broken packages (if there are any). Open Terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Again, maybe not needed but good to do, reboot the box once again. Now, try System Settings again.

The issue I helped another elementary user with stemmed from what we believed was system interaction while updates were applying. A good practice is that when updates are being applied through AppCenter is to close down all open apps, apply updates without any machine interaction then do a reboot.

Here is a link to the Reddit discussion [HERE](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/7ubt2u/extreme_noob_here_cant_open_system_settings/)

Hope this helps!!!!!

Comment: I am so sorry to say all of didn't help. The exact issue remains unchanged.

Comment: Very strange...if you were to open Switchboard via a command line, does there appear to be anything amiss? Also, it may be a long shot, but uninstalling Switchboard then reinstalling may be worth a try.

Comment: It was easier to just install another OS than to fix this issue. I just ended up installing Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome. I needed that functionality to do my work so I couldn't wait to fix it. Thanks for the thoughtful advice anyhow!